# Javascript Inline SVG Help Needed

Tags: javascript, svg, inline-svg

I am unable to translate the bar_position using javascript.

```
slider3.oninput = function() {
output3.innerHTML = this.value;
bar_position.style.transform='translate(0)';
}
```

See the Pen [Position Gauge](https://codepen.io/johnkelton/pen/9548bebf3a737367ef5b7326683df368/) by John ([@johnkelton](https://codepen.io/johnkelton)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0):

You have three numbers: `start`, `value`, and `end`. You can get the percentage `value` is between `start` and `end` with the following equation:

```
( value - minimum ) / ( maximum - minimum)
```

You can then convert that percentage to the UI by multiplying by the width of the element, which is hardcoded to be `50.834` pixels in the codepen:

```
const x = ( this.value - output1.innerHTML ) / ( output2.innerHTML - output1.innerHTML ) * 50.834;
bar_position.style.transform=`translate(${x}px)`;
```

Comment: Ok that works but same method doesn’t work when I want to rotate. I am unable to transform rotate the needle using slider. Needle at the center at "rotate(90 129.24 148.63)" right "rotate(180 129.24 148.63)" and left at rotate(0 129.24 148.63)
gauge_needle.style.transform=rotate(${this.value} 129.24 148.63)`;  https://codepen.io/johnkelton/pen/KewQLx